# Why activeElement.blur on a iframe is not working on Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, safari, blur

Consider the following demo:

frame.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="input">
    </body>
</html>
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe id="iframe" src="frame.html"></iframe>

        <script>
            console.log(document.activeElement);

            var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
            iframe.onload = function() {
                var input = iframe.contentDocument.getElementById('input');
                input.onfocus = function() {
                    console.log(document.activeElement);
                };
                input.onblur = function() {
                    document.activeElement.blur();
                    console.log(document.activeElement);
                };
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can run this on your local machine but you'll need a [local server](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/set_up_a_local_testing_server#Running_a_simple_local_HTTP_server) or you can check https://embed.plnkr.co/zrZiuvwBiAeQypwgl07J/preview

Steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Open your browser's console to see the logs (initially the activeElement is the parent/host/index page)
2. Click on the input to trigger focus (activeElement is now the iframe)
3. Click outside the input to trigger blur, I'm trying to also blur the iframe here with `document.activeElement.blur()` (activeElement is still the iframe in Safari but activeElement is the index page in other browsers)

So it looks like `activeElement.blur` in this scenario is not working properly in Safari. Anyone knows why? Could this be a bug in Safari?

I'm on macOS 10.13.3 using Safari 11.0.3.

Comment: Does this note on the activeElement page help at all? [Note: On Mac, elements that aren't text input elements tend not to get focus assigned to them.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/activeElement)

Comment: Not really. I've read that and this note is somewhat vague and generic. activeElement.blur works fine on Mac + Chrome for example. I'm trying to understand why this happens in Safari. Thanks anyway for trying to help.